# How to do nested SELECT without JOIN in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a Postgres query (via SQLAlchemy) that selects matching rows using complex criteria:

```py
original_query = session.query(SomeTable).filter(*complex_filters)
```

I don't know exactly how the query is constructed, I only have access to the resulting Query instance.

Now I want to use this "opaque" query (black-box for the purposes of this question) to construct other queries, from the same table using the exact same criteria, but with additional logic on top of the matched `original_query` rows. For example with `SELECT DISTINCT(column)` on top:

```py
another_query = session.query(SomeTable.column).distinct().?select_from_query?(original_query)
```

or

```sql
SELECT SUM(tab_value) FROM (
    SELECT tab.key AS tab_key, tab.value AS tab_value -- inner query, fixed
    FROM tab
    WHERE tab.product_id IN (1, 2)  -- simplified; the inner query is quite complex
) AS tbl
WHERE tab_key = 'length';
```

or

```sql
SELECT tab_key, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT tab.key AS tab_key, tab.value AS tab_value
    FROM tab
    WHERE tab.product_id IN (1, 2)
) AS tbl
GROUP BY tab_key;
```

etc.

How to implement that `?select_from_query?` part cleanly, in SQLAlchemy? 
**Basically, how to do `SELECT dynamic FROM (SELECT fixed)` in SqlAlchemy?**

---

*Motivation: the inner Query object comes from a different part of code. I don't have control over how it is constructed, and want to avoid duplicating its logic ad-hoc for each `SELECT` that I have to run on top of it. I want to re-use that query, but add additional logic on top (as per the examples above).*

Answer (score 3):

`original_query` is just a [SQLAlchemy query API object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html), you can apply additional filters and criteria to this. The query API is *generative*; each `Query()` instance operation returns a new (immutable) instance and your starting point (`original_query`) is unaffected.

This includes using [`Query.distinct()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct) to add a `DISTINCT()` clause, [`Query.with_entities()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities) to alter what columns are part of the query, and [`Query.values()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.values) to execute your query but return just specific single column values.

Use either `.distinct(<column>).with_entities(<column>)` to create a new query object (which can be further re-used):

```
another_query = original_query.distinct(SomeTable.column).with_entities(SomeTable.column)
```

or just use `.distinct(<column>).values(<column>)` to get an iterator of `(column_value,)` tuple results right there and then:

```
distinct_values = original_query.distinct(SomeTable.column).values(SomeTable.column)
```

Note that `.values()` executes the query immediately, like `.all()` would, while `.with_entities()` gives you back a new `Query` object with just the single column (and `.all()` or iteration or slicing would then execute and return the results).

Demo, using a contrived `Foo` model (executing against sqlite to make it easier to demo quickly):

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> class Foo(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "foo"
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     bar = Column(String)
...     spam = Column(String)
...
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
>>> session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
>>> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
2019-06-10 13:10:43,910 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("foo")
2019-06-10 13:10:43,910 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-06-10 13:10:43,911 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bar VARCHAR,
    spam VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2019-06-10 13:10:43,911 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-06-10 13:10:43,913 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
>>> original_query = session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.id.between(17, 42))
>>> print(original_query)  # show what SQL would be executed for this query
SELECT foo.id AS foo_id, foo.bar AS foo_bar, foo.spam AS foo_spam
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id BETWEEN ? AND ?
>>> another_query = original_query.distinct(Foo.bar).with_entities(Foo.bar)
>>> print(another_query)  # print the SQL again, don't execute
SELECT DISTINCT foo.bar AS foo_bar
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id BETWEEN ? AND ?
>>> distinct_values = original_query.distinct(Foo.bar).values(Foo.bar)  # executes!
2019-06-10 13:10:48,470 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DISTINCT foo.bar AS foo_bar
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id BETWEEN ? AND ?
2019-06-10 13:10:48,470 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (17, 42)
```

In the above demo, the original query would select certain `Foo` instances with a `BETWEEN` filter, but adding `.distinct(Foo.bar).values(Foo.bar)` then executes a query for *just* the `DISTINCT foo.bar` column, but with the same `BETWEEN` filter in place. Similarly, by using `.with_entities()`, we were given a new query object for just that single column, but the filter is still part of that new query.

Your added example works just the same way; you don't actually need to have a sub-select there, as the same query can be expressed as:

```sql
SELECT sum(tab.value)
FROM tab
WHERE tab.product_id IN (1, 2) AND tab_key = 'length';
```

which can be achieved simply by adding extra filters and then use `.with_entities()` to replace the columns selected with your `SUM()`:

```
summed_query = (
    original_query
    .filter(Tab.key == 'length')  # add a filter
    .with_entities(func.sum(Tab.value)
```

or, in terms of the above `Foo` demo:

```
>>> print(original_query.filter(Foo.spam == 42).with_entities(func.sum(Foo.bar)))
SELECT sum(foo.bar) AS sum_1
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id BETWEEN ? AND ? AND foo.spam = ?
```

There are use-cases for sub-queries (such as limiting results from a specific table in a join), but this is not one of those.

If you do need a sub-query, then the query API has [`Query.from_self()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_self) (for simpler cases) and [`Query.subselect()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery).

For example, if you needed to select only aggregated rows from the original query and filter on the aggregated values via `HAVING`, and then join the results with another table for the highest row id for each group and some further filtering, then you need a subquery:

```
summed_col = func.sum(SomeTable.some_column)
max_id = func.max(SomeTable.primary_key)
summed_results_by_eggs = (
    original_query
    .with_entities(max_id, summed_col)      # only select highest id and the sum
    .group_by(SomeTable.other_column)       # per group
    .having(summed_col > 10)                # where the sum is high enough
    .from_self(summed_col)                  # give us the summed value as a subselect
    .join(                                  # join these rows with another table
        OtherTable,
        OtherTable.foreign_key == max_id    # using the highest id
    )
    .filter(OtherTable.some_column < 1000)  # and filter some more
)
```

The above would only select the summed `SomeTable.some_column` values where that value is greater than 10, and where the highest `SomeTable.id` value in each group. This query *has* to use a sub-query, because you want to limit the eligible `SomeTable` rows before joining against the other table.

To demo this, I added a second table `Eggs`:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
>>> class Eggs(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "eggs"
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Foo.id))
...     foo = relationship(Foo, backref="eggs")
...
>>> summed_col = func.sum(Foo.bar)
>>> max_id = func.max(Foo.id)
>>> print(
...     original_query
...     .with_entities(max_id, summed_col)
...     .group_by(Foo.spam)
...     .having(summed_col > 10)
...     .from_self(summed_col)
...     .join(Eggs, Eggs.foo_id==max_id)
...     .filter(Eggs.id < 1000)
... )
SELECT anon_1.sum_2 AS sum_1
FROM (SELECT max(foo.id) AS max_1, sum(foo.bar) AS sum_2
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY foo.spam
HAVING sum(foo.bar) > ?) AS anon_1 JOIN eggs ON eggs.foo_id = anon_1.max_1
WHERE eggs.id < ?
```

The `Query.from_self()` method takes new entities to use in the outer query, if you omit those then all columns are pulled out. In the above I pulled out the summed column value; without that argument the `MAX(Foo.id)` column would also be selected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear. The `distinct` was just one example. I updated the question with one more example. Can you show how you'd achieve that?

Comment: @user124114: do realise you are now moving the goal posts with a much more complex query transformation. Your update doesn't actually tell me what part of that query is the original query (is it the inner query part? Is that inner part now limited in the number columns it returns? etc.Your query doesn't actually make much sense as a nested query, you'd more efficiently use `SELECT SUM(tab.value) FROM tab WHERE tab.product IN (1, 2) AND tab.key = 'length'`, which follows the exact same patterns (add a filter and sum). You'd still follow the same principle however: use the Query object API.

Comment: The question remains the same, I only clarified the wording. Your suggestion doesn't apply unfortunately, because this question is about nested queries. I don't have (easy) access to the inner query, if you read the question & comments inside more closely.

Comment: I added a `Motivation` section; hopefully it's clearer what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: @user124114 sure, you want encapsulation and that’s exactly how it should be. SQLAlchemy supports encapsulation out of the box, because`Query` objects are immutable and all methods return a new instance for you (it is a *generative* API)

Comment: @user124114 and your example doesn’t need to be a nested query. It *shouldn’t* be a nested query (even if the database query optimiser will un-nest it for you)

Comment: Very good. To keep on topic and avoid extended discussions: do you know how to implement those `SELECT additional_query FROM (SELECT fixed_query)` examples in SqlAlchemy? I'm still no nearer to my goal (if it's even possible).

Comment: @user124114: actually, I thought i'd already added in the extra information on using `Query.from_self()` or `Query.subselect()`, but I'm at a conference and the WiFi bandwidth in the auditorium ate my post edit. Sorry about that. I've recovered of it what I could, and perhaps can add an example later.

Comment: @user124114: there, I added a complex example for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through that tonight. But can you please remove the irrelevant bits, like "rewriting original query" or "using join", that directly contradict the question? Just to make the answer a little easier to navigate and digest.